# Oracle 9i ignores query alias sent from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

The following code is from a released version of an application using framework version 1 and Oracle 9i.

```
strSQL = "SELECT COURSE_CODE AS CODE FROM COURSE_REVISIONS WHERE DOC_REF_CODE = '" & doc_ref_prevcode & "'"

objDataset = stkDataAssistant.getTable(strSQL)

course_code = objDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Course_Code").ToString
            Response.Redirect("../Courses/CourseRevisionNew.aspx?flag=add&course_code=" & course_code)
```

It is throwing an error on the following line:

```
 course_code = objDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Course_Code").ToString
```

It is known that there is an error in the sql string with the alias CODE. This issue was being ignored in the clients environment and was working until a month ago that is now throwing an error in the stated line above.

Is this error showing up now because of some sort of framework change? Or is it with Oracle?

The client states that there has been updates to the server where the database resides but the application was still working as expected. The error started showing up 3 months later and there has no changes done to either the database or application environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle 9i has been out of support for many, many years. However you have to work with what you have, try this:

```
SELECT "COURSE_REVISIONS"."COURSE_CODE" 
FROM "COURSE_REVISIONS" 
WHERE "COURSE_REVISIONS"."DOC_REF_CODE" = 'QDMSPROD';
```

Or you could make a view with the alias that you want  and select from that.